# (Racket) Return a sublist of a list that satisfy a condition

Tags: functional-programming, scheme, racket

I'm having trouble writing a function that returns a sublist of pairs that satisfy a condition.

Current code:

```
(define lst1 '((a . 8)(b . 3)(c . 1)(d . 9)(e . 4)))

(define (letter t)
  (caar t))

(define (numb p)
  (cdar p))

(define (satisfy? c? lst)
  (cond
    [(or (c? (letter lst)) (c? (numb lst))) #t]
    [else #f]))

(define (find-sublist c? lst)
  (cond
    [(satisfy? c? lst) (cons (car lst) (find-sublist c?(cdr lst)))]
    [else (find-sublist c? (cdr lst))]))
```

Console input:

```
(find-sublist (lambda(x) (> (numb x) 3)) lst1)
```

Wanted output:

```
'((a . 8)(d . 9)(e . 4))
```

My current input consists of contract violations of either cons or pair

```
car: contract violation   
     expected: pair?   
     given: '()

cdar: contract violation
      expected: (cons/c pair? any/c)
      given: 'a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code:

- The `letter` and `numb` procedures operate on a list *element*, not on a *list*, so they should be just `car` and `cdr`.
- You forgot the base case, what should happen when the list is empty?
- Don't put `()` around `lst`, it's not a procedure.
- And more importantly: your `satisfy?` procedure attempts to operate on the letter `or` on the number, but in the `lambda` you *already* extracted the number. The solution is just to get rid of this procedure (or alternatively, don't extract the number in the `lambda`, but then you'll have to test if the `lambda`'s argument is a number before applying the condition.)

This should fix the issues:

```
(define (letter t)
  (car t))

(define (numb p)
  (cdr p))

(define (find-sublist c? lst)
  (cond
    [(null? lst) '()]
    [(c? (car lst)) (cons (car lst) (find-sublist c? (cdr lst)))]
    [else (find-sublist c? (cdr lst))]))
```

It works as expected:

```
(define lst1 '((a . 8) (b . 3) (c . 1) (d . 9) (e . 4)))
(find-sublist (lambda (x) (> (numb x) 3)) lst1)
=> '((a . 8) (d . 9) (e . 4))
```

FYI you reimplemented the built-in `filter` procedure. You should use existing procedures whenever possible ;)

```
(filter (lambda (x) (> (numb x) 3)) lst1)
=> '((a . 8) (d . 9) (e . 4))
```

Comment: (Numbered bullet points) 1. Yes true 2. If I already check that the list is not empty in another procedure do I still have to include this line? 3. Yes, typo. Edited 4. Ahhh this makes things much clearer! Thank you!

Comment: About 2: it doesn't matter that you checked it elsewhere, we're building a new list here, and at some point the recursion will turn `lst` into an empty list. All recursive procedures need a base case! And for building a new list by consuming an input list, the base case will always be to check for the empty list and return an empty list.

Comment: Your point (1) is incomplete: in the question, the letter and number functions operate on a list, not just a list element; their definitions matches the procedure `find-list`, which passes them the remainder of the list instead of just the first element. It's doubtless better to do as you did, and fix both of them to operate on just a single element; but the two procedures have to agree on the data that flows between them.

Comment: @OscarLopez Yes that makes sense! I accepted your answer. I upvoted your answer as well but I have less than 15 reputations so it won't appear publicly. Thanks again!